# Create a polygon filled with a clamp image in c#

Tags: c#, .net, polygon, system.drawing, bitmapimage

There is request to add one image on a certain position and inside of specific polygon on other image.

I have used following code:

```
private static void MergeBitmaps(string ImageFore, string ImageBack)
{
    try
    {
        Point point1 = new Point(833, 278);
        Point point2 = new Point(1876, 525);
        Point point3 = new Point(1876, 837);
        Point point4 = new Point(833, 830);

        Point[] curvePoints = { point1, point2, point3, point4 };

        Bitmap imgB = new Bitmap(ImageBack);
        Bitmap imgF = new Bitmap(ImageFore);
        Bitmap m = new Bitmap(ImageBack);
        System.Drawing.Graphics myGraphic = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(m);

        myGraphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        myGraphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        myGraphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        TextureBrush brush = new TextureBrush(imgF);
        brush.WrapMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.Clamp;

        myGraphic.FillPolygon(brush, curvePoints);
        myGraphic.Save();
        m.Save(@"new location", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

So, `imgF` should be placed inside of polygon determined by points on `imgB`. `imgF` should be stretched inside of that polygon, to fit. Reading documentation I found that this should be set up:

```
 brush.WrapMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.Clamp;
```

but it doesn't work. When it is turn on, `imgF` is not drawn at all. If that line is removed or set up like this:

```
 brush.WrapMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.Tile;
```

Then `imgF` is repeated several times.

So how to make `imgF` to be starched, to fit, to re-size and place inside of polygon?

I don't need rectangle, because it is not shape determined with same bottom and down edge or left and right edge.

Comment: Just do not use a TextureBrush! Revert what you're thinking: it's not the polygon to be filled with the bitmap but it's a **bitmap scaled and clipped by the polygon** (used as a region).

Comment: I need to have old image (**imgF**) displayed as polygon on other image, I don't want to clip any part of **imgF**. With clipping I will lose some parts of that image.

Comment: `With clipping I will lose some parts of that image.` If your polygon is not a rectangle, then of *course* you'll lose something.

Comment: Corey wrote right code for that. If you draw a bitmap inside a polygon then you'll always lose what's outside polygon because image has to be scaled to include all points. If you do not want to lose anything then you have to stretch bitmap to a polygon (but it's something completely different and little bit more complex). Try Corey's solution and if it's not what you need then...post here **example** images of result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Adriano gave you a clue as to how to do this.  Define a clipping region on the target image using the points of the polygon, then draw your bitmap with appropriate stretching to fill the target area.

Try this for example:

```
private static void MergeBitmaps(string ImageFore, string ImageBack)
{
    // Define output polygon and coverage rectangle
    Point[] curvePoints = new Point[] {
        new Point(833, 278), new Point(1876, 525), 
        new Point(1876, 837), new Point(833, 830)
    };
    Rectangle outRect = new Rectangle(833, 278, 1043, 559);

    // Create clipping region from points
    GraphicsPath clipPath = new GraphicsPath();
    clipPath.AddPolygon(curvePoints);

    try
    {
        Bitmap imgB = new Bitmap(ImageBack);
        Bitmap imgF = new Bitmap(ImageFore);
        Bitmap m = new Bitmap(ImageBack);
        System.Drawing.Graphics myGraphic = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(m);

        myGraphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        myGraphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        myGraphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        // Draw foreground image into clipping region
        myGraphic.SetClip(clipPath, CombineMode.Replace);
        myGraphic.DrawImage(imgF, outRect);
        myGraphic.ResetClip();

        myGraphic.Save();
        m.Save(@"new location", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```